# Update WMS layer OpenLayers + Angular?

Tags: openlayers, angular

I have an Angular map app with a WMS layer initialized as following:

```js
this.layer =
new ImageLayer({
  source: new ImageWMS({
    url: url,
    params: {LAYERS: this.getActiveLayers()},
    projection: proj
  })
});

this.map = new Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [this.layer],
  view: new View({
    projection: proj
  })
});
```

At some point I need to update the wms layer, so I create another `ImageWMS` with the new requirements

```js
this.auxLayer =
new ImageLayer({
  source: new ImageWMS({
    url: url,
    params: {LAYERS: this.newLayers()},
    projection: proj
  })
});
```

How can I update the `layer` with the new `auxLayer` info?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply update the params in the existing source

```
this.layer.getSource().updateParams({LAYERS: this.newLayers()});
```

Answer (score 0):

Easily solved using this:

```js
let source: new ImageWMS({
    url: url,
    params: {LAYERS: this.newLayers()},
    projection: proj
})
```

And then using the `layer` variable:

```js
this.capaPropia.setSource(source);
```